# How do I make the the page numbers appear on the right using \pagestyle{fancy} and section headings of the left?

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, typography

Cosndier the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rsfso}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=200,sortcites=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}
\mainmatter
\chapter{one}
\section{a}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{b}
\lipsum[1-20]
\chapter{two}
\section{c}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

As we see at the top of the page, the headings of each section are on the right while page numbers are on the left. How can we flip this so that section headings are on the left while page numbers are on the right?

Comment: Please reduce you code. Currently there are a lot of packages completely unrelated to the problem and some are even loaded more than once. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
    \usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{rsfso}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{babel, arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{upgreek}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{nicematrix}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{tabularray} 
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    \usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
    \usepackage{ae}
    \usepackage [english]{babel}
    \usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
    \usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=200,sortcites=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
    \allowdisplaybreaks
    
    \usepackage{mwe}
    \usepackage{undertilde}
    \usepackage{dsfont}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{ae}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    
    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \newpage
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[OL]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{one}
    \section{a}
    \lipsum[1-20]
    \section{b}
    \lipsum[1-20]
    \chapter{two}
    \section{c}
    \lipsum[1-20]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: you should really clean up your code. You are using packages which are obsolete (ae) or contradict each other.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you clean it up? feel free to edit the code.

Comment: no. you should do it. Only you know which of the package you really need. At best remove everything that readd only the one you know why.